# UWP: ListBox item not getting selected in an AppBarButton-flyout

Tags: c#, listbox, uwp

I have come across a strange issue:
When I have a ListBox included in a AppBarButton-Flyout:

```
 <Page.TopAppBar>
            <CommandBar>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Add">
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
<Flyout x:Name="TestFlyout">
                        <ListBox>
                            <ListBoxItem Content="A" />
                            <ListBoxItem Content="C" />
                            <ListBoxItem Content="D" />
                            <ListBoxItem Content="e" />
                            <ListBoxItem Content="F" />
                            <ListBoxItem Content="A" />

                        </ListBox>
                    </Flyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar>
        </Page.TopAppBar>
```

The items get not selected (they should be highlighted in blue). The same Listbox in a Button Flyout is working:

```
  <Button Content="Click me" IsEnabled="True">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <ListBox>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="A" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="C" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="D" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="e" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="F" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="A" />

                    </ListBox>
                </Flyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
```

At first I thought maybe it's a graphical issue, but I've tried to bind the `SelectedItem` property to a settter. But the setter is never called.
I just can't find my mistake here.

[image: Here the issue]

**Edit:**

Seems to be an issue with my machine. On other Windows-10 it's working like a charm.

Comment: It works for me on desktop (-> I can select any items and the selected item is highlighted in blue...). Have you tried it in a plain new XAML page?

Comment: @gregkalapos: I've created a blank new app for this.

Comment: Ok, i now also see it on your gif. For me they got selected... (they will be blue for me in both cases) can you maybe upload your visual studio solution?

Comment: @gregkalapos: Thanks, tried on a different machine, and there the same app is working. Seems to be an issue with my device.

Comment: great to hear! ...that was also my original thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `AllowFocusOnInteraction` property to `true` on the `AppBarButton`.

### Solution in XAML (for Windows 10, version 1607)

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="myAppBarButton"
              AllowFocusOnInteraction="True">
...
</AppBarButton>
```

or if you are targeting **Windows 10 Anniversary update** (1607) build 14393 or higher, but the app's **minimum Windows 10 version is lower**, you should check if the `AllowFocusOnInteraction` property is available on the platform.

So you can't set the `AllowFocusOnInteraction` property in XAML. Instead, do it in code-behind:

### Solution in C# code-behind

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsPropertyPresent("Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement", "AllowFocusOnInteraction"))
     myAppBarButton.AllowFocusOnInteraction = true;
```

You can also wrap it into an attached property that can be used in XAML even on all Windows 10 versions.

### More info

You're running into *a new feature* on **Windows 10 Anniversary update** (1607), build 14393.

That's an improvement for most app bar uses but interferes with yours, so you'll need to override the default value when you change your build to rather 14393 instead of 10586.

Here's a blog post [ComboBox on a Flyout attached to an AppBarButton loses mouse input on 1607](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2016/09/14/combobox-from-an-appbarbutton-loses-mouse-input-on-1607/). It also contains the attached property implementation.